# C# Error Finding Method in DLLImport

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have a C++ assembly that I am importing using DLLImport.

I am attempting to call its method:

```
namespace Testing
{
class Test{
int Run(char* filePath, bool bEntry, double duration){//code}
};
}
```

by

```
[DllImport(dllName, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int Run(string filePath, bool bEntry, double duration)
            );
```

When I call its method, I get the error message:

**Unable to find an entry point named Run in dll**

Comment: What kind of dll? Written in C?

Comment: I am guessing this is not a COM dll. Are you sure that the `Run` function in the DLL is exported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Run" looks to be a non-static class method. Although, it's possible to call such methods from C# this is not the primary use-case. It would be way easier to consume it from .NET if you expose it via COM, or at-least as a plain C interface:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* Testing_Test_Create();
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Testing_Test_Destroy(void* self);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Testing_Test_Run(void* self, char* filePath, bool bEntry, double duration);
```

And here is a sample how to call C++ class methods from C#:

```
// Test.cpp in NativeLib.dll
namespace Testing
{
    class __declspec(dllexport) Test
    {
    public:
        explicit Test(int data)
            : data(data)
        {
        }

        int Run(char const * path)
        {
            return this->data + strlen(path);
        }

    private:
        int data;
    };
}
```

```
// Program.cs in CSharpClient.exe
class Program
    {
        [DllImport(
            "NativeLib.dll",
            EntryPoint = "??0Test@Testing@@QAE@H@Z",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern void TestingTestCtor(IntPtr self, int data);

        [DllImport(
            "NativeLib.dll",
            EntryPoint = "?Run@Test@Testing@@QAEHPBD@Z",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int TestingTestRun(IntPtr self, string path);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
            TestingTestCtor(test, 10);

            var result = TestingTestRun(test, "path");

            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(test);
        }
    }
```

Entry point names might be different for your build configuration/compiler, so use dumpbin utility to obtain them. Again, this is just a proof of concept, in real code it would be better to use COM.

Comment: I have added extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) in the header file but I get the error message at compile time:  Command line error D8016 : '/GL' and '/ZI' command-line options are incompatible cl

Comment: That disappeared after setting Whole Optimization in Project's properties to "No" but now I get the error message: 'extern' storage-class specifier illegal on members

Comment: I am still interested in how you claim `it's possible to call such methods from C#` other than COM, plain C or a static C++ function.

Comment: @leppie: here it is. Actually .NET offers pretty good facilities for interoping with C/C++ code, so you can do almost anything as long as you know how it looks like at the low-level.

Comment: @Konstantin Oznobihin: Thanks +1. I am aware on a low-level it could work, but I had no idea it would not be so messy! Very nice indeed :)

Comment: Thank you Konstantin Oznobihin for helping.  What is "EntryPoint = "?Run@Test@Testing@@QAEHPBD@Z""  is it ?MethodName@ClassName@Namespace@@ what do I need instead of QAE...? Thank you again :)

Comment: @leppie - this is wrong, ThisCall is for instance methods.  Can't make instance methods work, there is no reliable way to get the object constructed.

Comment: Why am I getting the error message "Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL"?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: It's called "name mangling". Since C++ supports functions and methods overloading, there should be a way to distinguish methods with the same name, but different arguments. So C++ compilers encode method signatures into their names.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: did you get entry points via "dumpbin /EXPORTS"? What is the output? Again, I strongly discourage you from going this way. It's very easy to make it all wrong if you don't understand how it's working (and even if you do).

Comment: @Hans Passant: What is wrong and what is the problem with constructing objects?

Comment: Calling the constructor is painful, but technically solvable.  Getting the size of the object is unsolvable, only the C++ compiler knows it.  And don't forget the destructor.

Comment: @Hans Passant: You can't get the size of the object from C# code, but you can't get methods/functions declarations as well. This is something you are supposed to provide, and it's very easy to know the size from C++ code. Destructors are mostly the same as any other function call, what issues could you get with them?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used dumpbin.exe  I have searched my entire machine but unable to find dumpbin.exe. Would you know where it is?

Comment: I have one at "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin". You could also try using ordinals instead of names. I.e. change entry point to "#1".

Comment: I used DependencyWalker.exe in the mean time to open the dll and I get the error message "MSVCR90D.DLL was not found."

Comment: @Konstantin Oznobihin for the effort that you have put in, I will mark this as an answer :-) and also up voted it.  if you find any thing on "MSVCR90D.DLL was not found", please do let me know. thanks

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: It means the DLL is not there.

Comment: thanks leppie, do you know where I can get this DLL? I have installed VC++ runtime.

Comment: This is usually just an issue of DependencyWalker. As long as you can load your dll there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: thanks  Konstantin Oznobihin, I found dumpbin but when I executed \Exports, I found the error "The program can't start because mspdb80.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://dotnetperls.com/dllimport

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help if the function is a member of a class, but to locate the entry point by name, not ordinal, you'll need a .def file in your dll..

```
LIBRARY  mylib
    Run @1
```