# Export a C++ DLL function and import into C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, dllexport

So I am trying to export a function in a DLL that was developed in C++ into a C# project.  After digging around online and doing some book research as well I found a means to do so.  However my exposure to this is limited and all my knowledge is self taut so I am sure that I messed something up somewhere.

I am exporting the function like so:

```
STDMETHODIMP __export DataSetpImpl::set_HeaderFile(BSTR Value)
```

and importing it as such:

```
public unsafe class test
{
  const string _dllLocation = "DllPath.dll";
  [DLLImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.stdCall)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bstr)]
  public static extern string set_HeaderFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String path);
}
```

then call it in the application as followes:

```
test.set_HeaderFile(@"C:\temp\SomeHeaderFile.hdz");
```

everything builds correctly and links up just fine... the issue appears when the application hits the above call.  It throws and error saying:

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'set_HeaderFile' in DLL 'DLLPath.dll'.
```

any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  Also please keep in mind my knowledge on this subject if very limited, I am just going off what I could find online and in notes around the office.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Error Finding Method in DLLImport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885091/c-sharp-error-finding-method-in-dllimport)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can only import non-class member functions.

The name "set_HeaderFile" in your case is mangled into something like "DataTableImpl$$set_HeaderFile@4" and even if it is declared as static, the CLR won't find this in your .dll file using the name "set_HeaderFile".

You can make a workaround.

Say you have a

```
DataSetpImpl* g_Instance;
```

Then write a function

```
LONG __stdcall mySetHeaderFile(BSTR Val)
{
    return g_Instance->set_HeaderFile(Val);
}
```

and then in C# you can access it.

```
[DLLImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.stdCall, EntryPoint="mySetHeaderFile")]
public static extern Int32 set_HeaderFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String path);
```

Returning BSTRs also require some wrapping using the Marshalling. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx

Comment: Okay that makes sense... the issue is my exposure to C++ is non-existant and I do not have means to contatct the original developer...  So all I need to do it create the DataSetImpl * g_Instance; use that to replace the STDMETHODIMP DataSetImpl::set_HeaderFile(BSTR Value)?

Comment: See Seva's answer also. The COM marshalling can be done in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Well, there are no "closures" for C++, so to call the method of an object you've got to have the object itself. If you now where this object is, then declare the g_Instance and store the pointer to that object there. Or just replace the g_Instance by the name of the object in your code.

Comment: OKay So I declared g_Instance wehere the object is and exported the LONG __stdcall mySetHeaderFile instead of the original set_HeaderFile and complied/built it. Now in the C# code I imported the newly exported function and call that method.  I am still confused on the Marshalling of the return type so that will require a little more digging but so for this is making a lot more sense thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: Looking at the C++ code it has come to my attention that it looks as though the return type is not a BSTR but in fact an HRESULT... how does one go about handling that?

Comment: Probably, you just have to use the [In,Out] modifier for the "String path" parameter in C#

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13227/discussion-between-jimmy-and-viktor-latypov)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing two ways of interaction with managed code. You can wrap your code in a COM server and take advantage of .NET's COM interop facility. Or you can make a nonclass (i. e. globally scoped) exported function and use P/Invoke.

The wording of the function suggests COM. But on the C# side you use P/Invoke, wrongly.

I suggest that you use P/Invoke. COM is a big topic; unless you're willing to learn A LOT, don't go there.

For P/Invokable function, make a non-class function. You cannot consume exported C++ classes from DLLs via P/Invoke. The two class systems - managed and C++ - are quite distinct. Also, you don't have to pass BSTR's around, P/Invoke is fine with good old LPCWSTRs.